# VC 2017 runtime install hangs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msvcrt

I'm having an issue with running the latest VC 2017 runtime install (vc_redist.x86.exe) on Windows 10.  Previous versions didn't have an issue, but the latest (14.12.25810) seems to.

Here's the problem:
I'm launching the vc_redist.x86.exe install from another program with the /passive /norestart command line parameters.

Sometimes the VC runtime install will hang (become non-responsive) for several minutes.
In the log file I find the following:

MSI (s) (A4:E8) [14:29:57:505]: Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x86 Minimum Runtime - 14.12.25810. The file C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll is being used by the following process: Name: OfficeClickToRun , Id 7036.

MSI (s) (A4:E8) [14:29:57:506]: Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x86 Minimum Runtime - 14.12.25810. The file C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll is being used by the following process: Name: explorer , Id 4548.

It sounds like it can't install while those other processes are running. However, the previous versions of the VC runtime (e.g. 2015) didn't have this issue.

Has anyone else run across this and have a solution?

Comment: Using /norestart when a restart is necessary to solve this sharing problem is surely an issue.  Always favor local deployment.

Comment: @HansPassant would you mind clarifying your response? Thanks

Comment: I cannot guess what is unclear.  Run it again but now without /norestart and see what happens.

Comment: `/norestart` just suppresses the automatic reboot; it does not alleviate nor even attempt to alleviate the need for a reboot afterwards. As such, whether the switch is given or not, the installer should be able to do the pre-reboot phase of its job no matter what else is running. By all means try without it but this is not the direction I would intuitively expect to yield any fruit. However, since Hans's rather cryptic comment seems to exude confidence in that as a solution, we shall see.

Comment: (Unless the semantics of the flag have changed in VS 2017, that is)